# if else bash script

Tags: bash, jenkins

I have the following bash script

```
if [[$NODE_NAME = "Node1"]]
then
    dir="../../test"
fi
```

that I use in Jenkins execute shell prompt.

It gives me an error saying `Slave1 command not found`.

I just want to check if the `$NODE_NAME` variable equals the value `"Slave1"`. How do I do that in `bash`?

Answer (score 7):

The `[[` operator (and its other half, `]]`) is actually a keyword, and as such needs to have a space on either side. While you're there, double quote your variables in case they contain spaces or other unexpected punctuation:

```
if [[ "$NODE_NAME" == 'Node1' ]]
then
    dir="../../test"
fi
```

As for checking the variable's value, just echo it. Add this line above your `if` condition:

```
echo "NODE: $NODE_NAME"
```

Comment: Quoting any variable expansion is a good practice, just that, inside `[[ ]]` isn't strictly needed.

Comment: It *might* be necessary on the right-hand side, if you want to ensure strict string matching when the expansion contains pattern metacharacters such as `*`, `[`, or `?`.