# Jenkins if statment

Tags: bash, jenkins

I am trying to write a simple If statement on the Execute Shell of Jenkins (1.638). 
I looked on  [similar issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239852/if-else-bash-script)   and it still didn't work (see below the result output).
I tried both [[ and [ and relevant spaces, It appears that Jenkins handles if differently than on regular bash. I even tried the then on the same line as the if with ;. Any idea ?

```
if [[ "${BRANCH_NAME}" == "master" ]] || [[ "${BRANCH_NAME}" == "master_dev" ]]
then
    ./runUnitTests.sh ${REPOSITORY_NAME} ${BASE_BUILD_CORE} ${BRANCH_NAME} ${BUILD_NUMBER} || echo "The npm may fail but the report exists"
fi
```

The result on Jenkins is

- [[ upgrade == master ]]
  /tmp/hudson11669113852432623.sh: 2: /tmp/hudson11669113852432623.sh: [[: not found
- [[ upgrade == master_dev ]]
  /tmp/hudson11669113852432623.sh: 2: /tmp/hudson11669113852432623.sh: [[: not found
  [core] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson7252947297480815560.sh

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? Errors? Doesn't run?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you considered including a bash shebang in your shell?

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
if [[ "${BRANCH_NAME}" == "master" ]] || [[ "${BRANCH_NAME}" == "master_dev" ]]
....
```

That will force Jenkins to use your local bash interpreter.

Comment: Great solution. The only problem is that when I use the shebang, It route the output to a different place and so you can't see if what happened. Jenkins behavior is a Debug mode. So to over come this I had add -x to the shebang.  like this : #!/bin/bash -x

Comment: @Chen You can also just use the compatible `[` instead of the `bash`-specific `[[`:  `[ "${BRANCH_NAME}" = "master" ]`

Comment: Yes, as you found you'll need to use -x to get the output echoed to your Jenkins log.  I find a lot of folks use -xe to get the output and exit on error as well.

Comment: Thanks, I was going crazy with this. Just forgot to add the bash shebang

Comment: What does `-xe` mean? I saw similar issues of this type but without `-xe` - is that mandatory for Jenkins?

Comment: @ManuelJordan 
`-x`: This option enables debugging by printing each command and its arguments to the standard error output (stderr) before executing it. 

`-e`: This option causes the script to exit immediately if any command it runs exits with a non-zero status (i.e., fails).
 
So, when you use `#!/bin/bash -xe` at the beginning of your script, it will print each command and its arguments to stderr before execution and will exit immediately if any command fails.

Comment: @MichaelJ Huge thanks for the polite answer.

Comment: @ManuelJordan no problem!  I realize now, i didn't really answer your question. :) No, the `-xe` is not required for Jenkins... but it is very helpful for debugging jobs.

Comment: @MichaelJ Thanks again!